# Define custom system classloader

Tags: java, classloader

I'm trying to tell the JVM to use my custom ClassLoader as default ClassLoader

This is the VM argument i use to pick my class:

```
-Djava.system.class.loader=JarClassLoader
```

and this is the error i get

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: JarClassLoader.<init>(java.lang.ClassLoader)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: JarClassLoader.<init>(java.lang.ClassLoader)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SystemClassLoaderAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(Unknown Source)
```

Do i have to define a specific method or am i using the wrong argument?

Comment: Is your classloader really in a default package? Does it extend from ClassLoader and override all required methods?

Comment: Actually this is a Class Loader defined by someone else to check if the optional argument i'm using works correctly. Do you have any resource where i can read which are "all the required methods"?

Comment: You can read through [this](http://www.javablogging.com/java-classloader-2-write-your-own-classloader/) tutorial, its pretty helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Custom ClassLoader

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader{

    public CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader classLoader) {
        super(classLoader);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Loading class :" + name);
        return super.loadClass(name);
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting main");
    }
}
```

VM arguments: `-Djava.system.class.loader=CustomClassLoader`

All classes are in default package and it executes successfully.

*Output:*
**Loading class :Main

Starting main**

Comment: Tried that, I am getting:Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.IllegalStateException: recursive invocation